# Moving cursor to character below jums to the next line

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the example below, I'd like to move the cursor one character below, to go to the '**s**' letter in
the word '**perspiciatis**'. But instead, the cursor jumps to the **`>`** character in **`</li>`**

Which setting do I need to change to achieve that?

Caveats:

- I've got Toggle Word Wrap enabled
- I use VIM extension. This happens in both, Insert and Normal mode
- This is a HTML file

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `gj` is what you're looking for.  It moves the cursor down, if the line is wrapped, it keeps it in the same column that it appears to be in.

Comment: Sorry but there must be another setting interfering with the normal behaviour. The cursor jumps to the next line using ``gj`` too